# How to change the contents of a div from old data to new data using slideshow effect using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Let's say I have a div A, and I have an array of text data.

At t=0, div A will show `$data[0]`. After every `n` seconds, I want the div to show the next record available in the array.

I would like to create a transition effect similar to [this slideshow effect](https://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/curtain-fall.php). In this transition effect, user should be able to see that `$data[n]` is slowly sliding from the center of the div to the bottom, while `$data[n+1]` is slowing sliding from the top to the center of the div.

Is it possible to do this using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: show us your trials .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this out :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner">click me</div>
    <div class="inner">im a text</div>

</div>

$("#container").on("click",function() {
  $( "#container" ).animate({
      top: "-=100%",

  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

here is a [**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cqpcezm5/1)